# Slick slider react styling prev next

Tags: reactjs, slick.js

Is there a way I could customize prev next buttons with https://github.com/akiran/react-slick - all custom components examples are for using different images - but how do I position then side by side to bottom right corner - ? I am doing it with absolute position but getting messed up for smaller resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can define in css

```
.PrevButton {
  position: absoulute;
  transform: translateX(-50%)
  left: calc(50% - 20px)
}

.NextButton {
  position: absoulute;
  transform: translateX(-50%)
  Right: calc(50% + 20px)
}
```